# Strange code which compiles

Tags: objective-c

I have written in my code something like this and the strange thing is it's working!

```
 MKAnnotationView *mapViewIzan = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] 
     initWithAnnotation:annotation 
     reuseIdentifier:reuse];;;;;;
```

Why does this code compile and work? You can see that I have added ";;;;;"

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If the code works, why is there a problem?

Comment: a semicolon by itself is valid in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All statements in Objective C are terminated by a `;`.

```
do();;
```

is just the same as

```
do();
```

followed by an *empty statement that does nothing*, which is a totally valid thing in Objective C.

Your `;;;;;` is only a number of empty statements doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon `;` is a valid statement in C (and therefore in Objective C). This statement does not do anything - it represents an empty operation.

In your example this statement is not necessary, but there are cases when it is important. For example, copying C strings can be done as follows:

```
while (*dest++ = *src++);
```

The semicolon at the end is essential to the working of this construct.